# How to start 80E502Q8IH model lenovo laptop with DOS OS 1.1.6a of 2006 version

Tags: freedos

I have bought a new laptop lenovo 80E502Q8IH model.It is having just DOS OS ,how could i start my laptop ? in DOS version only.

Answer (score 1):

FreeDOS is a free MS-DOS-compatible operating system  with no enhancements or advanced features such as multitasking, protected mode operation, or GUI, only the command line. As soon as you install any operating system on your new laptop, you no longer need FreeDOS.

Normally you would get the installation media for the operating system of your choice and install an operating system on your laptop by overwriting the MS-DOS that was pre-installed on the Lenovo G50-80 (80E502Q8IH). This laptop has 4GB RAM, so you can benefit from installing a 64-bit operating system on it, if you have the installation media for a 64-bit operating system available.

Comment: Thank you ,so we must install windows in it ? upto then no use of this DOS  lap ?

Comment: If you are planning to install Ubuntu on your laptop you have the choice of installing either Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit or Ubuntu 15.10 64-bit, either of which can be directly upgraded to the next Long Term Support version of Ubuntu, Ubuntu 16.04 when it is released in April, 2016. Ubuntu Long Term Support releases provide a five-year period of support for software updates as well as technical support from the community at Ask Ubuntu Q&A, also for a five year period. Or you can install Windows, Linux Mint, Fedora or any other Linux distribution of your choice.

Comment: If you have ever used the cmd window in Windows, FreeDOS looks like that only with less features.

Comment: Is there any steps to start my lap starting in DOS OS

Comment: I don't know what the step are for the Lenovo G50-80, but when I installed Ubuntu on a laptop that came with FreeDOS pre-installed, I had to press the Delete key on the keyboard as soon as I saw the splash screen when the computer was booting in order to enter the UEFI setup utility. Then I had to change the boot order in the UEFI setup utility so that my installation media (a USB flash drive) was the first device in the boot order. Then I saved the changes in the UEFI settings and continued on to boot from my Ubuntu live USB installation media.

Comment: Most Linux distributions let you boot the operating system live from the installation media and try the operating system by running it live from the USB or DVD without installing it. This is the way you can test if the operating system is compatible with your laptop's hardware (i.e. integrated graphics and wifi).